# Conditional Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, inner-join

I want to be able to inner join two tables based on the result of an expression.

**What I've been trying so far:**

```
INNER JOIN CASE WHEN RegT.Type = 1 THEN TimeRegistration ELSE DrivingRegistration AS RReg
ON
RReg.RegistreringsId = R.Id
```

RegT is a join I made just before this join:

```
INNER JOIN RegistrationTypes AS RegT ON R.RegistrationTypeId = RegT.Id
```

This SQL-script does not work.

So all in all, if the `Type` is 1, then it should join on the table `TimeRegistration` else it should join on `DrivingRegistration`.

**Solution:**

In my select statement I performed the following joins:

```
INNER JOIN  RegistrationTypes AS RegT ON R.RegistrationTypeId = RegT.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TimeRegistration AS TReg ON TReg.RegistreringsId = R.Id AND RegT.Type = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN DrivingRegistration AS DReg ON DReg.RegistreringsId = R.Id AND RegT.Type <>1
```

Then I edited my `where-clause` to output the correct, depending on the `RegType`, like this:

```
WHERE (CASE RegT.Type WHEN 1 THEN TReg.RegistreringsId ELSE DReg.RegistreringsId END = R.Id)
```

Comment: You can't do it that like! `CASE` cannot be used to dynamically swap in and out random parts of the query. Do these tables have the same structures?

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try putting both tables in the query using LEFT JOIN's

```
LEFT JOIN TimeRegistration TR ON r.rid = TR.Id AND RegT.type =1 
LEFT JOIN DrivingRegistration DR ON r.rid = DR.Id AND RegT.type <>1
```

Now, in you select clause, use

```
CASE RegType.Type WHEN 1 THEN TR.SomeField ELSE DR.someField END as SomeField
```

The other option is to use dynamic SQL

Comment: Awesome, both Sparky and David's suggestions helped! Will edit my question to what I have done to make it work.

Answer (score 12):

You probably need to perform two left joins, one onto `TimeRegistration` and one onto `DrivingRegistration`, and return the fields you want from the appropriate join table something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN TimeRegistration ON TimeRegistration.RegistreringsId = R.Id
LEFT JOIN DrivingRegistration ON DrivingRegistration.RegistreringsId = R.Id
```

and you select statement would be something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RegT.Type = 1 THEN TimeRegistration.Foo ELSE DrivingRegistration.Bar END
```

I like what you're trying to do, but I don't think SQL is that clever.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  R.foo, tr.bar
FROM
  SomeTable AS R
  INNER JOIN RegistrationTypes AS RegT ON R.RegistrationTypeId = RegT.Id 
                                          AND RegT1.Type = 1
  INNER JOIN TimeRegistration AS tr    ON /* whatever */

UNION 

SELECT
  R.foo, dr.bar
FROM
  SomeTable AS R
  INNER JOIN RegistrationTypes AS RegT ON R.RegistrationTypeId = RegT.Id 
                                          AND RegT1.Type = 2
  INNER JOIN DrivingRegistration AS dr ON /* whatever */
```

Comment: +1 although will probably need to be `UNION ALL`. If the tables are Union compatible these could be in a CTE with a `type` column to avoid repeating the `JOIN` logic though not sure what the execution plans would look like.

Comment: @Martin: With the right indexes, the two joins should be plenty fast. I assumed since the two target tables are different, a UNION ALL would not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a scenario where there were three email columns in one table (don't ask why) and any of them could be null (or empty). In this example code I will just deal with a case where it is null.

I had to join it to another table by any of the emails to retrieve the users firstname.

Here is what worked

```
select  

m.email1,
m.email2,
m.email3, 
m2.firstName

from MyTable m

left join MyOtherTable m2 on m2.Email = 
case when m.email1 is null then 

    case when m.email2 is null then 

        case when m.email3 null then 
            'nonexistent@mydomain.com' -- i stopped here
        else m.email3 end

    else wm.email2 end

else m.email1 end
```

Obviously you would include further conditions like

```
case when m.email1 is null or m.email1 = '' then ...
```

To cover for empty values.