# SQL do inner join if condition met

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want a good way to improve my sql code, i have to use inner join when condition is met. I am currently replicates the code:

```
@SystemMerge bit

if (@SystemMerge=1)  
BEGIN
   SELECT
         .......
      FROM myTable
      INNER JOIN table ON table.param1=myTable.param1
      INNER JOIN systemTable on systemTable.param2=myTable.param2
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
      SELECT
         .......
      FROM myTable
      INNER JOIN table ON table.param1=myTable.param1
   END
```

and i would like to do it in a way like this:

```
@SystemMerge bit
BEGIN
   SELECT
      .......
   FROM myTable
   INNER JOIN table ON table.param1=myTable.param1
   ***//the next 4 lines is not working, but this pseudo of what i want:***
   if (@SystemMerge=1)  
   begin
      INNER JOIN systemTable on systemTable.param2=myTable.param2
   end
```

**edit:**
the solution (thanks to @Damien_The_Unbeliever):

```
LEFT JOIN systemTable ON systemTable.param2=myTable.param2
WHERE 
   ((@SystemMerge=1 AND systemTable.param2 is not null) 
   OR
   (@SystemMerge=0 OR @SystemMerge is null))
```

Comment: show us the code that isn't working. why isn't it working whats the error your getting? maybe an example of some data

Comment: You may want to use dynamic sql

Comment: You can build dynamic query based on condition and execute that query later with EXEC(query).

Comment: dynamic query example : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/generate-dynamic-sql-statements-in-sql-server/

Comment: C'Mon, is it so hard to do a search for "Conditional Inner Join"? google will give you e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268604/conditional-inner-join

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should (approxmately) do the same thing:

```
SELECT
     .......
  FROM myTable
  INNER JOIN table ON table.param1=myTable.param1
  LEFT JOIN systemTable on systemTable.param2=myTable.param2 and @SystemMerge = 1
  WHERE (@SystemMerge = 0 OR systemTable.NonNullableColumn IS NOT NULL)
```

Of course, this also means that any other references to columns within `systemTable` must be written to expect such columns to be `NULL`.

Comment: not helping in my case but i keep your answer for future needs. thanks.

Comment: OK, i have improved the answer and now it works good. thanks. picked you.

Answer (score 6):

How about dynamic sql?

```
declare @sel varchar(max)

set @sel = ' SELECT
         .......
         FROM myTable
         INNER JOIN table ON table.param1=myTable.param1
        '

 if (@SystemMerge=1)  
   begin
     set @sel = @sel+'INNER JOIN systemTable on systemTable.param2=myTable.param2'
   end

exec(@sel)
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple way if I am right -

```
SELECT
    .......
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN table ON table.param1 = myTable.param1
INNER JOIN systemTable on @SystemMerge = 0 or systemTable.param2=myTable.param2
```