# How to join two table based on condition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are three table A,B,C

A table columns are Name,ID,Address

B table columns are ID,Address,School

C table columns are School,address,cafe

If Name='A'
Then Table A and Table B will join based on A.ID =B.ID

IF Name='B'

Then Table A and Table B will join based on A.ID =B.ID and A.Address=B.Address

And this result with join with Table C

Comment: did you try anything ? or did you google this for any result ? just check this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828117/sql-do-inner-join-if-condition-met

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code :

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
INNER JOIN B 
  ON (   (B.Name = 'A' AND A.ID = B.ID) 
      OR (B.Name = 'B' AND A.ID = B.ID AND A.Address=B.Address)
     )
```

You can now join the result with table C

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR` and `AND` operator to simulate `if` condition in `ON` clause. Try this `Join`

```
SELECT *
FROM   A
       INNER JOIN B
               ON ( A.name = 'A'
                    AND A.ID = B.ID )
                   OR ( A.Name = 'B'
                        AND A.ID = B.ID
                        AND A.Address = B.Address )
       INNER JOIN C
               ON B.school = C.school
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming there A.Name is either A or B:

```
SELECT *
FROM   A
  JOIN B ON ( A.ID = B.ID )
            AND ( A.Name = 'A' OR A.Address = B.Address )
  JOIN C ON B.school = C.school
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
    INNER JOIN C
    ON B.SCHOOL = C.SCHOOL
WHERE A.NAME = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B
    ON A.ID =B.ID and A.Address=B.Address
    INNER JOIN C
    ON B.SCHOOL = C.SCHOOL
    WHERE A.NAME = 'B'
```

This might work